# Two functions for the same thing, one crashes and the other does not, why?

Tags: javascript

I want a function called findFirst that takes parameters n and q and returns the smallest prime number dividing n that is greater than or equal to q. So first I wrote a function that would say if a number is prime or not.

```
var isPrime = function(n){
    if(n === 1){
        return false;
    }
    else if (n === 2 || n === 3){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        for(i=2; i < n; i++){
            if(i * i >= n){
            for(j=2; j<=i; j++){
                    if(n % j === 0){
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            return true;
            } 
        }
    }
};
```

There could be other ways to make this more efficient, but I am pretty sure this function is not the problem.

So with this function I made my first attempt to write findFirst:

```
var findFirst = function(n,q){
    var p = q;
        while(n % p !== 0 || isPrime(p) === false){
            p++;
        }
    return p;
};
```

This function works, but with large numbers it crashes, for example it crashes on input (6310545154, 3). By the way the prime power decomposition of 6310545154 is 2 * 3155272577

So I wrote another function that would first just list the prime factors of a number:

```
var getFactors = function(n){
    var factors = [];
    var k = n;
    var p = 2;
    while(isPrime(k) === false && k !== 1){
        while(k % p !== 0 || isPrime(p) === false){
            p = p+1;
        }
        while(k % p === 0){
            k = k/p;
        }
        factors.push(p);
    }
    if(isPrime(k) === true){
        factors.push(k);
        return factors;
    }
    if(k === 1){
        return factors; 
    }
};
```

And now my second attempt at findFirst is:

```
var findFirst = function(n,q){
    var array = getFactors(n);
    var p = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] >= q && p === 0){
            p = array[i];
        }
    }
    return p;
};
```

This one works great. It doesn't crash on that large number above and computes the result instantly. Can anyone see why this would happen? It seems like the 'while' loop in my original attempt is pretty similar to one of the 'while' loops in the getFactors function. And the second attempt looks a lot more complicated.

Comment: You say what `q` is for; what about `n`?

Comment: It doesn't crash it just takes really long to compute, it returns `3155272577` is that the expected output?

Comment: @cheeken: You're right, that should say "returns the smallest prime number dividing n that is greater than or equal to q". I will edit it.

Comment: @Musa: maybe your computer has more power or something, but I get a chrome message saying the page is unresponsive. 3155272577 is the expected output and both attempts will produce that. I am wondering why the first attempt takes a long time and/or crashes, while the second works instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second program returns very quickly because your number only has one large prime factor; once it's found (all) the small prime factor(s) it quickly exits its loop. The first program has to count all the way from 3 up to 3155272577 before it discovers that it's a factor. After 2147483647 it has to switch from integer to floating-point arithmetic, which makes it even slower.

Note that

```
var isPrime = function(n) {
    ...
};
```

is an unusual way of creating a function; normally you would write

```
function isPrime(n) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I get it, that makes sense. It still has to check that 3155272577 is prime, but I guess the square root is small enough to not crash my browser. Thanks for you help, and thanks for the syntax tip. I am new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

You have whole lot of bugs, in the code - for example, this way `i` is the global variable

```
for(i=2; i < n; i++){
```

What you want to do is

```
for(var i=2; i < n; i++){
```

Then later

```
factors[i] = k;
```

Where `i` is not defined and so on.

Run your code through jslint or jshint to make it fully correct first.

Comment: The factors[i] = k; is a typo, I pasted the code here, then went back and changed it in the code, but forgot to change both lines here. As for your other comment on the for loops, there isn't a problem, the code works fine. Keep in mind that in my question I never said that the code failed to run, just that one took a long time and other worked quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for prime number real quick with regex.

```
function isPrimeNumber(n) {
    return !/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/.test((new Array(++n)).join('1'));
}
```

Read more on [this post](http://www.noulakaz.net/weblog/2007/03/18/a-regular-expression-to-check-for-prime-numbers/).

**Edit:** Maybe not optimal for large numbers though. More like a quick solution.

Comment: I am not familiar with regex. This whole project is just me trying to practice what I know. I will keep your function in mind in the future, although it doesn't seem to work past 7 digits. The one I wrote seems to work pretty quickly up to around 15 digits, after that it starts running slow, at least on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly address the question, but I think it's important to stress that **an unresponsive tab is NOT the same as a crash.** Unresponsive simply means that the page's been executing JavaScript for a really long time.

Remember, there's no way for the browser to know for sure whether a script will ever complete without running the script - that's called the **halting problem,** and for a turing-complete programming language it's not solvable. The browser's offer to kill the script is based on a **guess**, and this is true no matter what the script in question is.

Comment: You're right, I was using "crash" when I should have said "unresponsive". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The second attempt never executes `p = p+1;` and in fact executes the whole `while` only 2x in this `getFactors` part:

```
   while(k % p !== 0 || isPrime(p) === false){
        p = p+1;
    }
```

unlike the first attempt which has to test every number of `p` from '3' to  `3155272577` for primality and factor of `n` in the first attempt:

```
    while(n % p !== 0 || isPrime(p) === false){
        p++;
    }
```

**Why?**
The second attempt starts with     `var p = 2;` and     `var k = n;` which means `(k % p === 0)` and `isPrime(p)` are both `true` (when `n=6310545154`)

```
while(isPrime(k) === false && k !== 1){
    while(k % p !== 0 || isPrime(p) === false){
        p = p+1;                                               /*  this is never executed for findFirst(6310545154, 3)  */
    }
    while(k % p === 0){
        k = k/p;
    }
    ...
```

and then `k = k/p;` immediately reduces  `k` to `3155272577` which terminates the outer `while(isPrime(k) === false ...`

To observe the same aberrant time behaviour in the second attempt, use:
`var factors = [2];` and `var p = 3;` .

ref:   [Eratosthenes Sieve - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)